# How to initialize Scrollbar at the top in QT

Tags: c++, qt, initialization, scrollbar, minimum

I've got a QGraphicsView with a vertical Scrollbar, but the problem is that when I run my app, the scrollbar position is set to the center of the QGraphicsView.

How can I set it to the top by default ?
I tried to use :

```
view->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
```

But it doesn't change a thing. However, I tried this too :

```
view->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(1);
```

And it does change the Scrollbar Position to the top, but not at its minimum.

Comment: What is the range of your vertical scrollbar? Does the graphicsview have any content?

Comment: The graphicsview does has a content (A Pixmap, using QGraphicScene). Using the minimum() and the maximum() methods of the scrollbar, it tells me that: 0 is the minimum and 2082 is the maximum.

Comment: What is your pixmap's [scene position](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitem.html#scenePos)?

Comment: I use multiple part of the pixmap using QGraphicsPixmapItem. Their positions go from 0,0 to 0,2048.